# Do I have to rewrite all my Java server if I want to write a servlet?

Tags: java, database, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a Java standalone application with the following things:

- A database.
- A server which accesses a Database and accepts requests from the clients.
- A client programmed with MVC pattern which updates the database through the server.

Now I want to do a web page from which clients can update  the database. I know that I have two options here: java web services and servlets. I would prefer using a servlet because  java web services requires installing software and that would prevent some devices of using the application.

My question is: do i have to rewrite most of the code of my server to implement the servlet or it is just add and change some things of my server code?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you structured it when you first wrote it. Hopefully, if you were clever, then no.

Comment: You can try springboot rather than just a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a server component that is servicing requests from clients. You just need to extend this with an HTTP server that will accept and handle requests from HTTP clients.

You will probably want to run in a container, such as Tomcat. If you go this route, you will want to implement a ServletContextListener to initialize/cleanup your existing application on startup/shutdown.

You will then use the container (e.g., Tomcat) to start the whole server (existing and new web endpoints). You will probably want to have the web stuff hit one port (e.g., 80 or 443) and some other port for your existing client connections.

For each of your existing request handlers that you want to make available via HTTP, you will want to refactor your code so that all of the data validation and business logic are implemented by a single method (you may well have written it this way to begin with). Then you add a web service to handle the HTTP request and have it call the same method as your existing server implementation calls.

You may want to consider using one of the many web service frameworks that are out there (e.g., Jersey).